# Disk Utility will not let me create new partition

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I am attempting to create a new partition from a 3TB Fusion Drive on Mavericks, but Disk Utility won't allow it. I successfully created a partition from the same drive last month, so I am not sure why it won't allow me to create another one. Does this have something to do with the Fusion Drive? Is there a workaround?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: So what happens when you click on the + sign ?

Comment: Nothing. The + sign is greyed out.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you partition the whole drive to be the Mac drive.

To undo that and create multiple partitions follow following procedure.

[How to Partition A Fusion Drive](http://macperformanceguide.com/Fusion-partitioning-howto.html)
<sub>Last updated January 10, 2013</sub>

[See Controlled Fusion: Partitioning for Targeted Performance.](http://macperformanceguide.com/Fusion-partitioning.html)

Shown below are two partitions of the Fusion drive in Disk Utility.

To partition a Fusion drive:

```
Backup your stuff (two backups strongly recommended).
Boot off any working drive (e.g. one of your backup clones).
Erase the Fusion drive (because your stuff might not fit on a downsize partition).
In the Partition tab, click the + button.
Drag the slider between the partitions to size as desired.
Set a name for the 2nd partition.
Apply.
Clone your system back to the new Boot volume (if too large, move some items first to the new 2nd volume).
Copy your other data (data not going onto the Boot volume) onto the 2nd volume.
Set the startup volume to the new Boot volume, reboot.
```

Comment: So there's no way to do this without erasing all my data first?